# Question in Milnor's Morse Theory

Tags: differential-geometry, morse-theory

In Milnor‘s book 'Morse Theory' p12 and p13, the proof of Theorem 3.1, which is

> Let $f$ be a smooth real valued function on a manifold $M$. Let $a < b$ and suppose that the set $f^{-1}[a,b]$, consisting of all $p \in M$ with $a < f(p) < b$, is compact, and contains no critical points of $f$. Then $M^a$ is diffeomorphic to $M^b$. Here $M^a=\{x\in M,f(x)\leq a \}$

he claim

> Choose a Riemannian metric on $M$, $<.,.>$,define $grad f$ by $<Y, grad f> = Y(f)$. Define $\rho:M \rightarrow\mathbb{R}=1/<grad f, grad f>$, and $X_q = \rho(q) (grad f)_q$, then $X$ generates a 1-parameter group of diffeomorphisms $\phi_t:M \rightarrow M$. By caculation, $t\rightarrow f(\phi_t(q))$is linear with derivative $+1$ as long as $f(\phi_t(q))$ lies between $a$ and $b$. And then he claim **$\phi_{b-a}:M\rightarrow M$ is clearly a diffeomorphism from $M^a$ onto $M^b$**, I wonder why it is such a diffeomorphism, I can not find it clear.

Comment: $\phi_{b-a}$ is smooth and $\phi_{-(b-a)}$ is an inverse since $\phi_0:M\to M$ is the identity and $\{\phi_t\}_t$ is a 1-parameter group of diffeos.

Comment: @Warlock of Firetop Mountain Yes, but why it is a bijection between $M^a$ and $M^b$?

Comment: Because the gradient of $f$ has been normalized, thus the function $f$ increases by $t$ as you follow the flow for time $t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} (f \circ \phi_q)(t) &= (df)_{\phi_q(t)} (X_{\phi_q(t)}) \\
&= (df)_{\phi_q(t)} \Big( \rho(\phi_q(t)) \cdot \text{grad}f)\Big)\\
&= \rho(\phi_q(t)) \cdot \text{grad} f(f) \\
&= \rho(\phi_q(t)) \cdot \langle\text{grad} f, \text{grad} f \rangle_{\phi_q(t)} \\
&= 1
\end{align}
This means that $(f \circ \phi_q)(t) = t+f(q)$, and so the formula help to give $\phi_{b-a}(M^a) = M^b$.

Comment: Could you please say something about why $\phi_{b-a} $ is surjective? I do not think it is clear, for $x\in M^b$, how to find $x\in M^a$, s.t. $\phi_{b-a}(x)=y$

Comment: @Grey We know that for any $x \in M^b$, we have $y \in M$ such that $\phi_{b-a}(y) = x$. We only need to verify that indeed $y=\phi_{a-b}(x) \in M^a$. That is to verify $f(y) = f \circ \phi_{a-b}(x) \leq a$.